# Fade image on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

i'm trying to fade an image on scrolling with the following code:

html:

```
<img th:src="@{/img/bc.jpg}" class="top" onscroll="myFunction()"/>
```

css:

```
.top {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

js:

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

function myFunction() {
var myElement = $('.top');

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    myElement.css({
        'opacity': 1 - st / 600
    });
});
}

</script>
```

It wont work, and since its my first time using JQuery, i figured the issue is probably import-wise? I tried to do this without putting the js code in a function aswell, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you dont need to specify the scroll function in html(inline)

```
<img th:src="@{/img/bc.jpg}" class="top"/>
```

Second your executive code should be in `$(document).ready` event of jQuery

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var myElement = $('.top');
       $(window).on('scroll', function () {
         var st = $(this).scrollTop();
         myElement.css({
            'opacity': 1 - st / 600
         });
      });
    });
</script>
```

[JSFiddle demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/q5h1ocyw/1/)

That should work

Comment: Are the 2 <script> tags on purpose?

Comment: I had a import problem, thanks alot, great solution!

Comment: What would you modify to make a picture below it fade a bit slower?

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is not clear enough for me, please check my concept below. When window is scroll down, we will detect that if scroll space from top is bigger than 100px, the image will be faded out (hide) and as opposite scroll the image will be faded in (show). You can use it as simple codes.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      var element = $('.top');
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
          element.fadeIn();
        }
        else {
          element.fadeOut();
        }
       });
    });
</script>
<img th:src="@{/img/bc.jpg}" class="top"/>
```